# React Native Polling

Tags: react-native, polling

I'm trying to implement some api polling code, this is what I've got so far:

```
async retrieveNotifications() {
  const res = await fetch(url)
  if (res.status === 200) {
    this.props.setNotifications(res.data)
  }
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.retrieveNotifications()
    // polling in 10 min cycles
  }, 600000);
}
```

the code works, however the question is if this has any performance downsides because its recursive? Does anyone know a better solution for polling in rn ? Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about the performance implications of recursion here (or even if a setTimeout closure counts as recursion exactly), but you could use `setInterval` to call a polling method every 10 minutes, without needing to daisy-chain the calls. And don't forget to use [clearInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp) when you want it to stop!

For example:

```
async retrieveNotifications() {
    const res = await fetch(url)
    if (res.status === 200) {
        this.props.setNotifications(res.data)
    }
}

//inside some class method
setInterval(this.retrieveNotifications, 600000);
```

Comment: Is there an easy way this works with async await ? I don't like working with promises ^^

Comment: I think it will just work... the async/await pertains to what happens inside your method. The interval won't wait on it, but the code inside your method should behave like before. Example added above.

Comment: I really appreciate your help guy, your code almost worked, it somehow returned undefined as res.data like this, I had to make a fat arrow function out of retrieveNotifications for it to work, ill post the working code for anyone running into the same problem, it looks much better as you suggested

Comment: Study this for detailed usage of setInterval() clearInterval(). React Hooks will be much more optimised. 
https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/

Answer (score 0):

This is the improved code as suggested form @bmovement, thanks for your help :D

```
constructor() {
  super()
  // polling in 10 min cycles
  this.interval = setInterval(this.retrieveNotifications, 600000)
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.retrieveNotifications()
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  clearInterval(this.interval);
}

retrieveNotifications = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(url)
  if (res.status === 200) {
    this.props.setNotifications(res.data)
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, this causes performance issues, I have ended up using the following npm: react-native-background-timer

Comment: Thanks @Kape. That's helpful.